# How to show comma separated values of roles using Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, query-builder

[image]

One user can have many roles and I want to show my roles in comma separated values like

```
"role": "world","hello","john"
```

But currently I am getting roles against each user and that's creating repeated user in my listing because one user can have many roles. If I have 5 roles against one user it will create 5 listing against one user and there will be duplication of user email and id while fetching and I want to avoid:

This is my controller code:

```
public function getAllUsers()
{
    $users = DB::table('users')
        ->leftjoin('user_basic_info', 'users.id', '=', 'user_basic_info.user_id')
        ->leftjoin('roles', 'users.id', '=', 'roles.created_by')
        ->select('users.id', 'user_basic_info.*','roles.name AS role','users.email', 'users.created_at', 'users.updated_at','users.created_by')
        ->where('users.deletedAt', '=', null)
        ->where('roles.deletedAt', '=', null)
        ->orderBy('users.id', 'desc')->get();

    return response([
        'status' => true,
        'message' => "All Users",
        'total' => count($users),
        'data' => $users
    ], 200);
}
```

I can do that using eloquent but my response will change. Currently I am getting response:

```
    {
        "id": 14,
        "first_name": "farhan",
        "middle_name": "ahmed",
        "role": "world",
        "email": "shahzad_h12495@ovadamd.com"
    },
    {                           {
        "id": 14,
        "first_name": "farhan",
        "middle_name": "ahmed",
        "role": "hello",
        "email": "shahzad_h12495@ovadamd.com"
    },
```

As you can see duplication of email and id, I want one record against id 14 and with comma separated role like below:

```
        "id": 14,
        "first_name": "farhan",
        "middle_name": "ahmed",
        "role": "hello","world",
        "email": "shahzad_h12495@ovadamd.com"
```

How I can achieve this using query schema?

Comment: Can you check that responce as it does not look valid to me. Are you really getting that responce

Comment: yes bro i am getting that response

Comment: ignore the first name and last name same values but the response i am getting is exactly i am shared

Comment: Show that response to jsonlint.com Do you get errors as well as me ?

Comment: i have share screen shot , brother i just shown you 2 objects there is like 40+ records in my json

Comment: What is the eloquent query for the second example? and how do your database looks like?

Comment: Did you try `->distinct()->get();`

Answer (score 0):

The duplication can only be ignored in two cases :

- you use Eloquent and call roles as a relation
- you treat your data in a foreach and manually organise things.

The show question is a Front issue and not a Back issue, if you are using blade and roles as a relation, you can do as follows

```
    @foreach($user->roles as $role) 
        @if(!$loop->last) , @endif // 
        {{ $role->name }} 
    @endforeach
```

If you use Laravel Models, your query would be a million times easier to process with Eloquent :

```
User::with('roles)->->orderBy('users.id', 'desc')->get();
```

As you see, no need to joins as Eloquent will do them and no need to deleted_At == null as Eloquent will only grab those without deleted_At.